# ASP.NET multiple federated identity providers

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs

I am developing an ASP.NET application. I have successfully added an STS reference to a stand-alone AD FS 2.0 server, so I can authenticate against a 3rd party's active directory. The problem is that I have more than one client who wishes to be able to authenticate against their own active directory. It seems that I can only add one STS reference to a project. How do I add multiple identity providers to an ASP.NET application and then programatically choose which provider I want to redirect the browser to for authentication? Thanks!

Ralphie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the normal federation pattern.

You normally "bind" your application to one STS (say STS1) using FedUtil and then at the STS level federate with other STS (say STS2 and STS3). Then when the user accesses the application, WIF redirects to STS1 and you get a "Home Realm Discovery" screen that asks "Who would you like at authenticate against (STS1 / STS2 / STS3).

Your question doesn't indicate whether you already knew this or whether you are wondering how to authenticate against multiple STS.

**Update**: You can use VS to create a custom STS - not sure if HRD is out-the-box. What other authentication stores do you need to cater for? Why do you think you need a custom STS? You can use multiple instances of ADFS all federated against each other or federate ADFS with PingIdentity or OpenAM ... Have a look at [IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.com/). That's a custom STS which is a very good base to use.

**Update 2**: Yes - you are correct.

Comment: I have heard something similar. I have seen several people say they created a custom STS as a "Federated Provider." Is this something that works out of the box or will I need to write the custom STS and "Home Realm Discovery" screen? I am indeed wondering how to authenticate against multiple STS.

Comment: I see. So one possible setup is that I have ADFS installed on my domain controller. I add an STS reference to my asp.net website to that domain controller. That domain controller has claims trust relationships with N identity providers. When a user is directed to my STS reference, they will be presented with a home realm discovery page so they can choose between the identity providers. Does that sound right?